# Solution for "cannot find symbol" error with mouse events

Tags: java, applet, awt

I keep importing more packages but I get the same "error: cannot find symbol" with all of the methods containing mouse events.  I think I am missing a package or a class that needs to be extended or implemented, but I can't find which one.  Any ideas?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.*;

public class t1 implements MouseListener
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Create frame with title
        Frame frame = new Frame("Click Counter Project");

        // Create a component to add to the frame
        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Click");
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
    { 
            textArea.setText("Mouse pressed. x = "+ event.getX() + " y = " +         event.getY());
    } 
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
    { 
        textArea.setText("Mouse released. x = "+ event.getX() + " y = " + event.getY());
} 
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event)
{ 
    textArea.setText("Mouse clicked. x = "+ event.getX() + " y = " + event.getY());
    } 
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event)
    { 
        textArea.setText("Mouse entered. x = "+ event.getX() + " y = " + event.getY());
    } 
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event)
    { 
            textArea.setText("Mouse exited. x = "+ event.getX() + " y = " + event.getY());
    }
    public void t1()
    {
        frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            int width = 300;
            int height = 300;
            frame.setSize(width, height);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All required packages and files have been imported. The reason there is a "cannot find symbol" error is that because the "textArea" field and "frame" variables are local. Declare them as static class variables as done in the below code and then initialize them in the main method and the cannot find symbol error is cleared.

The code should be like this:-

```
 public class t1 implements MouseListener
    { 
    static TextArea textArea;
    static Frame frame;
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        // Create frame with title
          frame = new Frame("Click Counter Project");

            // Create a component to add to the frame
             textArea = new TextArea("Click");
             t1 clickCount= new t1();
        }
    ...
 t1()
    {
        frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            int width = 300;
            int height = 300;
            frame.setSize(width, height);
            frame.addMouseListener(this);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

Comment: That has cleared the error, but now the program does nothing when I execute it.  Any idea why?

Comment: Kindly try this above modified code from your given one to see your desired result. It is because you have used t1() method as a local variable, instead it should be the name of the constructor for the class t1.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `textArea` is declared as a local variable inside `main`, so it's out of scope inside other methods.

Declare `textArea` inside the class but outside of all methods -- as an instance variable.  Then it will be in scope for your entire class, including all of your methods.

```
public class t1 implements MouseListener
{
    // Here!
    final TextArea textArea = new TextArea("Click");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // ...
```

You will need to do the same thing with the `frame` variable.

Comment: What should I put in the main then?  It is empty and when I try to run it, nothing happens.

Comment: You'll need to call methods on the `Frame` object to get it to show itself.  You can find tutorials for this online.